# Translate WordPress Post Meta Data to another language

Tags: wordpress, localization, translation

The bellow code display the post date in English, e.g. September 13, 2017, instead of e.g. 2017年9月13. Do you see any error?

```
      $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
            if (get_the_time('U') !== get_the_modified_time('U')) {
                $time_string .= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
            }

            $time_string = sprintf($time_string,
                esc_attr(get_the_date('c')),
                esc_html(get_the_date()),
                esc_attr(get_the_modified_date('c')),
                esc_html(get_the_modified_date())
            );
            printf(__('<span class="posted-on"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> %3$s</a></span>', 'colormag'), 
                esc_url(get_permalink()), esc_attr(get_the_time()), $time_string
            );
```